# Hide NewItemPlaceHolder in ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with DataGrid and ListBox. Users can add new rows to datagrid, but an empty row is visible in listbox.

I found info about NewItemPlaceHolder, but I don't know how to hide it in listbox.

XAML:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="2"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingWithTriggers}"
         x:Name="ViewListBox"
         Background="AliceBlue"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter}}" >
```

CS:

```
public static readonly IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter Instance
                         = new IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter();

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (value != null && value.ToString() == "{NewItemPlaceholder}")
  {
    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }
  MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
  return value;
}
```

Comment: You should change your `ItemContainerStyle` template to check this `NewItemPlaceholder` instead of putting the check on the ItemsSource (which will anyhow contain an Enumerable of some class, and not a single value). You could then return Visibility.Collapsed to a visible property of your template

Comment: But I receive in my converter whole collection instead of single element. How should I add converter to list box to receive each of elements separately?

Comment: You have there an ItemContainerStyle that refers to some kind of Style template, this style template will be bound to the single item of your collection, so you could attach the visibility property of your style template to your converter based on the binding as you do in the listbox , and then you can remove the converter from your itemssource binding inside the listbox

Answer (score 0):

Create a new collection view (`SelectsView`) of `Selects` (`ObservableCollection` of `SelectItem`) and filter the view

```
 SelectsView = new();
 SelectsView.Source = Selects;
 SelectsView.Filter += SelectsView_Filter;
 SelectsListView.ItemsSource = SelectsView.View;
```

The view's filter

```
 private void SelectsView_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
 { 
     // Hide NewItemPlaceHolder         
     if (e.Item is SelectItem)
     {
         e.Accepted = true;
     }
     else
     {
         e.Accepted = false;
     }
}
```